# For i in loops in R

Tags: r

I have been really struggling to grasp a basic programming concept - the `for` loop. I typically deal with heirarchically structured data such that measurements repeat with levels of unique identifiers, like this:

```
ID  Measure
1   2
1   3
1   3
2   4
2   1
...
```

Very often I need to create a new column the aggregates within `ID` or produces a value for each row for each level of `ID`. The former I use pretty basic functions from either `base` or `dplyr`, but for the latter case I'd like to get in the habit of creating `for` loops.

So for this example, I would like a column added to my hypothetical `df` such that the new column begins with one for each `ID` and adds `1` to each subsequent row, until a new `ID` occurs.

So, this:

```
ID  Measure NewVal
1   2       1
1   3       2
1   3       3
2   4       1
2   1       2
...
```

Would love to learn `for` computing, but if there are other ways, would like to hear those too.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the `splitstackshape` package. There is a function called `getanID`. This is your friend here. If your df is called `mydf`, you would do the following. Please note that the outcome is data.table. If necessary, you want to convert that to data.frame.

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(mydf, "ID")

#   ID Measure .id
#1:  1       2   1
#2:  1       3   2
#3:  1       3   3
#4:  2       4   1
#5:  2       1   2
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Measure = c(2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "Measure"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

`seq_along` gives an increasing sequence starting at 1, with the same length as its input.  `tapply` is used to apply a function to various levels of input.  Here we don't care what is supplied, so you can apply the `ID` column to itself:

```
> d$NewVal <- unlist(tapply(d$ID, d$ID, FUN=seq_along))
> d
  ID Measure NewVal
1  1       2      1
2  1       3      2
3  1       3      3
4  2       4      1
5  2       1      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `ave`.  The advantage is that it will give the `sequence` in the same order as that in the original dataset, which may be beneficial in unordered datasets.

```
transform(df, NewVal=ave(ID, ID, FUN=seq_along))
#  ID Measure NewVal
#1  1       2      1
#2  1       3      2
#3  1       3      3
#4  2       4      1
#5  2       1      2
```

For a more general case (if the `ID` column is `factor` )

```
transform(df, NewVal=ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN=seq_along))
```

Or if the `ID` column is ordered

```
df$NewVal <- sequence(tabulate(df$ID))
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(NewVal=row_number())
```

data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Measure = c(2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "Measure"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: So many options to do this kind of task. Good to see all kinds of options.

Comment: @jazzurro Yes, but I like your approach.  It is compact.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `data.table` to assign the sequence by *reference*.

```
# library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)  ## convert to data table
mydf[,NewVal := seq(.N), by=ID]  ## .N contains number of rows in each ID group

#    ID Measure NewVal
# 1:  1       2      1
# 2:  1       3      2
# 3:  1       3      3
# 4:  2       4      1
# 5:  2       1      2

setDF(mydf)  ## convert easily to data frame if you wish.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you don't use a for loop for this. It's not a good place for one. You can do this pretty easily in`plyr` (or `dplyr`) if you prefer:

```
require(plyr)
x <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)))
x$ID <- sample(1:10, 100, replace=T)

new_col <- function(x) {
  x <- x[order(x[,1]), ]
  x$NewVal <- 1:nrow(x)
  return(x)
}

x <- ddply(.data= x, .var= "ID", .fun= new_col)
```